# MongoDB with Kotlin Serialization: How to ensure ID field is properly stored?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, serialization

I'm tryna rewrite my old class implementation to Kotlin mongo db but I see that the id is not being stored properly in the database and I can't figure out how to do it. Here is my old code implementation:

```
class ListRepo<E> : Repo<E> {
    private val list = ConcurrentHashMap<String, E>()

    @Suppress("KotlinConstantConditions")
    override fun create(element: E): Boolean =
        Item(element, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .let {
                list[it.id] = it.elem
                true
            }

    override fun read(): List<Item<E>> =
        list.map {
            Item(it.value, it.key)
        }

    override fun read(id: String): Item<E>? =
        list[id]?.let {
            Item(it, id)
        }

    override fun read(ids: List<String>): List<Item<E>> =
        ids.mapNotNull { id ->
            list[id]?.let {
                Item(it, id)
            }
        }

    override fun update(id: String, value: E): Boolean =
        if (list.containsKey(id)) {
            list[id] = value
            true
        } else false

    override fun delete(id: String): Boolean =
        list.remove(id) != null

}

    override fun create(element: E): Boolean =
        Item(element, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .let {
                list[it.id] = it.elem
                true
            }
```

And here my new implementation with mongo db:

```
class ListRepo<E>(private val collection: MongoCollection<E>) : Repo<E> {

    override fun create(element: E): Boolean {
        Item(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), element)
            .let {
                collection.insertOne(element)
            }

        return true
    }

    override fun read(): List<Item<E>> {
        return collection.find().map { element ->
            Item(element.toString(), element)
        }.toList()
    }

    override fun read(id: String): Item<E>? {
        return collection.find(Item<E>::id eq id).map { element ->
            Item(element.toString(), element)
        }.firstOrNull()
    }

    override fun read(ids: List<String>): List<Item<E>> =
        ids.mapNotNull { id ->
            collection.find(Item<E>::id eq id).map { element ->
                Item(element.toString(), element)
            }.firstOrNull()
        }

    override fun update(id: String, value: E): Boolean {
        val query = collection.find(Item<E>::id eq id).firstOrNull()
        collection.updateOne(
            and(Item<E>::id eq id),
            setValue(Item<E>::elem, value)
        )
        return query != null
    }

    override fun delete(id: String): Boolean {
        val query = collection.deleteOne(Item<E>::id eq id)
        return query.deletedCount > 0
    }
}
```

And I think that problem in **create** and **read** functions. Also I can't change this line of code, cause my logic gotta work with only generic type E (element):

```
class ListRepo<E>(private val collection: MongoCollection<E>) : Repo<E> {
```

I use this ListRepo like this:

```
private val client = KMongo.createClient("mongodb://root:example@127.0.0.1:27017")
private val mongoDatabase: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase("admin")

private val student = mongoDatabase.getCollection<Student>().apply { drop() }
private val lessons = mongoDatabase.getCollection<Lesson>().apply { drop() }

val studentsRepo = ListRepo<Student>(student)
val lessonsRepo = ListRepo<Lesson>(lessons)

fun createTestData() {
    listOf(
        Student("Sheldon", "Cooper"),
        Student("Leonard", "Hofstadter"),
        Student("Howard", "Wolowitz"),
        Student("Penny", "Hofstadter"),
    ).apply {
        map {
            studentsRepo.create(it)
        }
    }

    listOf(
        Lesson("Math"),
        Lesson("Phys"),
        Lesson("Story"),
    ).apply {
        map {
            lessonsRepo.create(it)
        }
    }

    val students = studentsRepo.read()
    val lessons = lessonsRepo.read()
    val sheldon = students.findLast { it.elem.firstname == "Sheldon" }
    check(sheldon != null)
    val leonard = students.findLast { it.elem.firstname == "Leonard" }
    check(leonard != null)
    val math = lessons.findLast { it.elem.name =="Math" }
    check(math != null)
    val newMath = Lesson(
        math.elem.name,
        arrayOf(
            GradeInfo(sheldon.id, Grade.A),
            GradeInfo(leonard.id, Grade.B)
        ))
    lessonsRepo.update(math.id, newMath)
}
```

sheldon variable for example is Item<Student> where Item has id and element:

```
typealias ItemId = String

@Serializable
class Item<E>(
    val id: ItemId,
    val elem: E,
)
```

So now, in my new implementation instead of id I get Student@113131 reference, which not correct, I except String Id.

```
@Serializable
class Student(
    val firstname: String,
    val surname: String
)

typealias StudentId = ItemId

val Student.json
    get(): String = Json.encodeToString(this)
```

How to fix my issue, how to rewrite code to mongo db properly, lemme know if anyone aware.

I try to change many times type of MongoCollection to Document or Pair or Map etc. But with my code logic I can't use this interfaces and classes cause AnySerializer won't work properly for this type and also getting data from this Document for example is kind painful.

```
val serializer: AnySerializer<T> = anySerializer()
    val itemSerializer: AnySerializer<Item<T>> = anySerializer()
    val listItemSerializer = ListSerializer(itemSerializer)
```

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> anySerializer(): AnySerializer<T> {
    return AnySerializer(Json.serializersModule.serializer())
}

class AnySerializer<T : Any>(private val dataSerializer: KSerializer<T>) : KSerializer<T> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = dataSerializer.descriptor

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: T) {
        val jsonEncoder =
            encoder as? JsonEncoder ?: throw SerializationException("This serializer can only be used with JSON")
        jsonEncoder.encodeJsonElement(Json.encodeToJsonElement(dataSerializer, value))
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): T {
        val jsonDecoder =
            decoder as? JsonDecoder ?: throw SerializationException("This serializer can only be used with JSON")
        return jsonDecoder.decodeJsonElement().let {
            Json.decodeFromJsonElement(dataSerializer, it)
        }
    }
}
```